# How do I get unique pairs of objects from a collection of objects?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linq, ienumerable

What I want is a slick way to do like

`{ A, B, C }` ---> `{ {A, B}, {A, C}, {B, C} }`

where `A`, `B` and `C` are of type `Widget` and `{ A, B, C }` is of type `Widget[]` and `{ {A, B}, {A, C}, {B, C} }` is of type `IEnumerable<Pair<Widget,Widget>>` or `IEnumerable<Tuple<Widget,Widget>>`.

Comment: well, any effort from your side?

Comment: sounds like some loops would be good, what algorithm did you use to generate the sample output you gave (a,b a,c b,c)

Comment: @drheart All combinations and unique pairs are not the same thing, wouldn't make sense to get all of the combinations and filter if you're just looking for the pairs

Comment: @konkked More like a partial duplicate, in that if this wasn't clearly a "Gimme teh codez" question, I would actually provide a response. But instead, I encourage the asker to review the possible duplicate for inspiration and either figure it out or come back with a proper question.

Answer (score 0):

Can do with a simple for loop, should give you the pairs you need **if you're looking for unique in terms of index**

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> UniquePairs<T>(T[] arr)
{
    for(int i=0;i<arr.Length;i++)
    {
      for(int j=i+1;j<arr.Length;j++)
      {
          yield return new[]{ arr[i],arr[j] };
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: If downvoter would like to provide feedback would gladly improve my answer